# Trying to identify dystopian scifi podcast

Tags: story-identification, podcast

I listened to this podcast 2-3 years ago, but in the interim time I stopped listening to podcasts due to lack of time. As I now have more time and am starting to listen to podcasts again I am trying to rebuild the collection I previously had.

This podcast was set on a space station that was run by an AI. The AI worked for a corporation and was very blatant about not caring for human life. The listener is meant to be a human worker on the station, doing whatever tasks the AI, who is the narrator, assigns them to do. These tasks often put the worker in blatant danger. Fairly early on in the podcast,

> The main "character" dies, at which point the episode switches perspectives >!without much fanfare.

I remember either the name of the podcast, the AI, or the corporation being Halcyon or something similar, but google searches along those lines has been less than fruitful, so I may be wrong.

Comment: This is confusing and interesting to me. I never knew there were fictional podcasts.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's tons, but a lot of times you have to find out about them through word of mouth because they don't advertise like TV shows or congregate in an easy to browse place like book stores. If you let me know what type of stuff you're into I might be able to give you some recommendations

Comment: @zabeus You might want to try glancing at http://theaudiodramadirectory.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***SAYER***](https://geeklyinc.com/category/sayer/page/7/), by Adam Bash. He apparently writes much of the show, and is the title character. In other words, he provides the voice of SAYER, the Artificial Intelligence working for Ærolith Dynamics, who explains the ground rules to the company's new laborers after they arrive on the asteroid called Typhon. Follow the link, and it will take you to a page which provides access to the first 9 episodes of the series. (And the rest of them are archived on the same site.)

I have just refreshed my memory by playing back Episode 1. Here's an excerpt from the dialogue to illustrate why I feel positive that this is the same podcast you fondly remember.

> "Your new home here in Halcyon Tower has everything you could ever
>   desire. It is truly a marvel of both architecture and urban planning.
>   And I can say without question that you will die here.
>
> "That seems to be distressing you, so perhaps I am not expressing my
>   meaning as clearly as I intend. I simply mean to say that it is nigh
>   certain that your death will occur here in Halcyon.  If a place
>   existed where your every desire could be fulfilled, would you ever
>   leave that place? As a rational thinker, the answer must inevitably be
>   . . . No. And so it is with that logic that I can deduce that you will
>   never leave Halcyon. So thinking about it that way, isn't that great
>   news?
>
> "You . . . still do not seem as cheerful about this as I would expect."

So you can see that you correctly remembered that "Halcyon" is a name mentioned in the podcast, though you were wrong about it being the name of the AI or the corporation.

Note: Last night, when I first saw your question, I *vaguely remembered* having once listened to at least the first episode, but I couldn't remember the series title off the top of my head. I figured if some diehard fan of the podcast were out there, and saw your question, then he was welcome to any rep points he could get by answering you. But tonight, when I saw that still hadn't happened, I poked around a bit and figured out which podcast you and I both remembered listening to.

Comment: This is the one, thanks!